# Setting imageURL using a function in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I've done this task before within repeaters and it has worked.  However I can't get the below to work for me in a normal webforms page.  The images appear as broken links and breakpoints I put in the codebehind are not triggered.

(in the aspx file)

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImageDirectory()%>btnRunReport.png'  />
```

(codebehind)

```
public string GetImageDirectory()
{
    return "~/App_Variants/LBSX/images/";
}
```

This is the second method I've tried, in the other one I tried passing the imagename through as a string, and it would return the entire link that way.  Still no luck!

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

[EDIT] Thanks for the help everyone.  In the end after the handy hints I found a recursive snippet which did the trick as follows:

```
private void UpdateImages(Control Parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls)
    {
        ImageButton i = c as ImageButton;
        if (i != null)
        {
            i.ImageUrl = "~/App_Variants/LBSX/images/" + i.ImageUrl;
        }
        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            UpdateImages(c);
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateImages(Page);
    ...
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Cheers

Comment: <%# - call on data-bind event.
<%= - call in render (normal usage).

you're looking for <%=

Comment: Yes, sorry I also have tried the <%= but still no breakpoint triggered.  What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Also, when I view source on the page, the control shows the src as:
src="&lt;%=GetImageDirectory()%20%>" rather than trying to pass whatever it calculates.
Maybe there's a clue there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, just like Zachary mentioned, you're using the code block for data binding.

Second, as you've already tried, using an inline expression (`<%= %>`) won't work either in your case, since you can't use an inline expression for any property of a server-tag.

What you could do instead is defining an image button using HTML syntax, omitting the `runat="server"` tag, and use the inline expression to get your image's URL:

```
<input type="image" src="<%= GetImageDirectory() %>btnRunReport.png" name="image" />
```

What an inline expression does is, it calls `Response.Write()` with the value between `<%= %>` as the parameter, e.g. `<%= this.MyVar %>` is `Response.Write(this.MyVar)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  What I'm trying to do is put a custom directory (depending on certain conditions) in front of the image name.  So in one case it may be images3/picture.jpg and in others it would be images4/picture.jpg.  I'm not using themes for various reasons.  Is there any way in the codebehind I could achieve the same by doing something like:

First, set imageURL at designtime to 'picture.jpg' without path
Then for each Imagebutton in (whatever the page object is)
ImageUrl = "mydirectory" + existing imageurl

Would that be workable do you think?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks to your guidance I've now managed to solve this.  Ended up iterating through the controls as mentioned and putting the path at the front.  Works a charm!  I will add code to the question for others reference.

Comment: I'm glad you could solve this. I've managed to write the code for iterating through the controls; if somebody's interested, you can find the mentioned code here: http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=27788#a27788

Comment: Thanks for that, much appreciated mate.  Note that the one I put above is recursive whereas yours seems to be nested to two levels.  Not sure if it ever goes below two levels, mind you... :)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is for data binding, <%# %>.  If you are just trying to do inline c#, you should use <%= %>.

Comment: Actually I should have mentioned, I've tried that also and no luck still!  Good point though, I did find various people saying that when I was searching forums etc.

Answer (score 1):

I give you another solution. Use [ExpressionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

1. Create a class devired from ExpressionBuilder and override function GetCodeExpression

   ```
    namespace your.namespace
   {
   public class CustomBuilder : ExpressionBuilder
   {
       public override CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(BoundPropertyEntry entry, object parsedData, ExpressionBuilderContext context)
       {
           Type type1 = entry.DeclaringType;
           PropertyDescriptor descriptor1 = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type1)[entry.PropertyInfo.Name];
           CodeExpression[] expressionArray1 = new CodeExpression[1];
           expressionArray1[0] = new CodePrimitiveExpression(entry.Expression.Trim());

           String temp = entry.Expression;
           return new CodeCastExpression(descriptor1.PropertyType, new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new
          CodeTypeReferenceExpression(base.GetType()), "GenerateLink", expressionArray1));
       }
       public static  String GenerateLink(String link)
       {
           return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaPath"] + link + "?ver=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaCode"];
       }
   }
   }
   ```

`expressionArray1` is the input array for `GenerateLink` function. You can change the size of array according to numbers of input params for your function

2.Register your expression in webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
      <expressionBuilders>

        <add expressionPrefix="GenLink" type="your.namespace.CustomBuilder"/>
      </expressionBuilders>

    </compilation>
```

3.In view your can use new expression:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="Server" ImageUrl='<%$ GenLink:images/magnifier.jpg %>'/>
```

4.Enjoy !!!