# Concat Web.config value and string in Image control SRC

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a web.config key :

```
<add key="IMGSRC" value="http://localhost" />
```

I want to use the value of this key along with the path of the image concatenated to in an aspx page. I'm aware that I can get to root folder by simply saying "../ImagesFolder" , but my website has parent path disabled because of security concerns. So now I need to work around it.

I need something like this (Here are a few things I tried after looking up the internet and which did not work.):

1)    `<img id="Img19" runat="server" alt="Admin" src='<%#ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["IMGSCR"] %>' />`

2)    `<img id="Img19" runat="server" alt="Admin" src='<%#ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["IMGSCR"] + "/ImagesFolder/img.jpeg" %> ' />`

3)
   `<img id="Img19" runat="server" alt="Admin" src="<%#ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["IMGSCR"] %> "  + "/ImagesFolder/img.jpeg" />`

Also I tried this: 
I declared a variable **Path** on `Page_Load`
Path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootforIMG"].ToString();

and then on aspx page I tried using it as
   `<img id="Img19" runat="server" alt="Admin" src="<%=Path %> "  + "/ImagesFolder/img.jpeg" />` but this as well is no good.

Comment: Take a look [on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373352/using-directory-getfiles-with-specifing-the-absolute-path/12373394#12373394) here on SO.

Comment: @Adriano In my case I have a lot of small images on a single page.I cannot make so many variables in codebehind by mapping each image with server.mappath().

Comment: you do not need to create variables. Just use Server.MapPath() inside your page instead of reading path from configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like below?

```
<img id="Img19" runat="server" alt="Admin" src='<%= GetImageSource()%>' />
```

In code behind

```
public string GetImageSource()
{
 return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IMGSCR"] + "/ImagesFolder/img.jpeg";
}
```

Comment: For finding application path,use this.. public string CurrentAppPath()                                  {return (System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath == "/") ? string.Empty : System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

    }

Comment: I would pass the `"/ImagesFolder/img.jpeg"` into the `GetImageSource()` function, otherwise you're doing way too much work.

Comment: What if I have a lot of images on a single page.I will have to make that many variables in code behind.

Comment: Better you call like src='<%= CurrentAppPath()+'imagefile'%>'

Comment: Both the methods tried, with <%= %> , it gives me a not "well formed" error, whereas with src='<%# CurrentAppPath()+'imagefile'%>' , it does not return a string.I mean when I view source, I see src="". Also I have a breakpoint on the method which does not get called.

Comment: Please remove runat='server' property from img. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278654/setting-imageurl-using-a-function-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

The relative path of images should work:

Relative path can be as per your page location i.e: '../IMages/img.jpg' or  'images/img.jpg'

try this :

```
<img id="Img19" runat="server" alt="Admin" src='ImagesFolder/img.jpeg' />
```

Answer (score 0):

For controls with `runat="server"` attribute you do not need any special code to map a path relative to web site root:

```
<img id="Img19" runat="server" alt="Admin" src"~/ImagesFolder/img.jpeg" />
```

The path `~/ImagesFolder/img.jpeg` will be resolved replacing `~` with the root folder of your web-site.

If to resolve path you need some kind of logic (for example you need to call a function) then you can use this:

```
<img src'<%= ResolveImageName() %>' />
```

Do not forget that URL must be proper encoded.