# asp.net image button's imageurl property not showing image of network location?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am upoloading image to below location:
**Location**:\MyPC-pc\u165121142\MyFolder\pid\11\Profile\FImage\
**But I cannot show the image from above location.**
 below is my control:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImgImage"   runat="server" />
```

I am checking using below method for file exists or not(it works) but when I set image file location to ImageUrl property, I can not see image in browser.

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists("\\MyPC-pc\u165121142\MyFolder\pid\11\Profile\FImage\Koala6192013104451AM.jpg"))
    {
        ImgImage.ImageUrl="\\MyPC-pc\u165121142\MyFolder\pid\11\Profile\FImage\Koala6192013104451AM.jpg";
    }
```

**note**: This folder (u165121142) is in network. I have given it full rights

Comment: how bout this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278654/setting-imageurl-using-a-function-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: thanx for the reply by this link is not useful for me. I am storing image on other computer's drive(suppose in your computer's drive(Having permission)). I successfully completed this task. Now I want to use this image from that location where i stored. Note: Hosting computer and the other computer in which i am storing image are in same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's browser needs to be able to retrieve from the URL.  It's retrieved at display time.

You could either put the file on a web server and use an http url, or you might be able to use a file: url.  Either way, the browser won't retrieve from a disk file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your actual code? 'Cause you probably need to use double backslash, like:

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists("\\\\MyPC-pc\\u165121142\\MyFolder\\pid\\11\\Profile\\FImage\\Koala6192013104451AM.jpg"))
    {
        ImgImage.ImageUrl="\\\\MyPC-pc\\u165121142\\MyFolder\\pid\\11\\Profile\\FImage\\Koala6192013104451AM.jpg";
    }
```